# How can I create a file starting at a specific sector on the disk?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, file-io

How can I create a file starting at a specific sector on the disk in Windows? Any programming language is acceptable. If it matters, the file system I am interested in is NTFS.

Comment: I really don't think you can do that, I can't think why you'd want to. Any defrag would instantly break whatever dependency you think you are creating.

Comment: file systems won't let you do that. this is what they like to abstract away for you. try using `dd` (check cygwin for instance), that might let you mess around! But you will probably be trashing the filesystem when you do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a file at a specific sector, but once you've created a file you can move it using the [FSCTL_MOVE_FILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) IO control code.  There's no guarantee that it won't be moved again later on, though.

Comment: Could you please post a code example of it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the source for cygwins `dd` command. That should point you in the right direction. I hope you know what you are doing. And: Don't do this to the system disk...

Comment: While you can _modify_ specific disk sectors using `dd` you cannot use it to _create a file starting at a specific sector_. You could use it to change an existing file without NTFS getting notice of you doing so. If the filesystem checksums data blocks (like e.g. Linux btrfs or Solaris ZFS), that'd be detected ...